# How to set default color in Colorfield

Tags: aem

I have a `Colorfield` for background color and I have provided set of different colors in items as follows -

```
<backgroundColor jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured"    sling:resourceType="granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/colorfield"
    showDefaultColors="{Boolean}false"
    text="Background Color"
    fieldLabel="Background Color"
    name="./backgroundColor"
    showProperties="{Boolean}false">
  <items jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured">
    <white jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" value="#FFFFFF"/>
    <black jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" value="#000000"/>
    <hugo-blue jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" value="#D8F1FF"/>
    <hugo-brown jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" value="#451A0C"/>
    <hugo-cream jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" value="#F6F6EC"/>
    <hugo-green jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" value="#AECDC7"/>
    <hugo-gray jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" value="#3C3C3C"/>
  </items>
</backgroundColor>
```

I want to set `hugo-green` as default color. I tried `defaultValue` but it only works fir `Select`. How can I do so? Can we set default color in Colorfield component in AEM 6.5?

Answer (score 1):

Yes we can set the default color to the colorfield by adding the the value(string). The value mentioned will be come as default.

Dialog Property field:-

[image]

Dialog colorfield with default value:-
[image]

ref: https://helpx.adobe.com/experience-manager/6-5/sites/developing/using/reference-materials/granite-ui/api/jcr_root/libs/granite/ui/components/coral/foundation/form/colorfield/index.html

Comment: Okay..!! Thank you so much!!